# Reusable functions between templates in Play Framework templates

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, scala-template

In Play Framework inside of a template I can define functions like that:

```
@title(text: String) = @{
  text.split(' ').map(_.capitalize).mkString(" ")
}

<h1>@title("hello world")</h1>
```

Can I define such function in separate file and make it reusable between multiple templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least several solutions:

**First** is using [**tags**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTemplateUseCases#Tags-(they-are-just-functions,-right?)) as *Makis* showed you and in most cases it's ok, even if it adds additional empty lines it doesn't matter (at least when we are talking about generating HTML snippets i.e. representing repeating news items on list) - you can i.e. optimize/compress your HTML in post-process if you care about transfer rates.

**Second** is creating a Scala object which contains static functions (in Java it's also possible) and returns the `play.twirl.api.Html("<div>your code</div>")`, this way you can programmatically fit your code exactly as you need, avoid empty lines, remove or replace spaces, etc. Just in your template you will need to use syntax like: `@full.qualified.path.to.Object.method("foo", "bar")` returning the `Html("...")` causes that you do not need to escape returned code within your view.

**Third** approach is using own *TemplateMagic-like* methods which allows you to *extend* objects of any type and perform some logic on it, good sample is `"active".when(someCondition)` syntax, you can see as it's done [**in the repo**](https://github.com/playframework/twirl/blob/master/api/src/main/scala/play/twirl/api/TemplateMagic.scala). Of course you need to just create custom class like this and the import it on the beginning of your view(s). Also keep in mind that it doesn't need to be only one `Boolean` argument, your methods can use as many parameters as you need - any type you need. It can be just parameterless.

edit - sample:

**app/myapi/MyMagic.scala**

```
package myapi

import play.twirl.api.Html

import scala.language.implicitConversions

object MyMagic {

  class RichString(string: String) {

    def upperWords() = {
      Html(string.split(' ').map(_.capitalize).mkString(" "))
    }

    def bold() = {
      Html("<b>" + string + "</b>")
    }

    def when(predicate: => Boolean) = {
      predicate match {
        case true => string
        case false => ""
      }
    }

  }

  implicit def richString(string: String): RichString = new RichString(string)
}
```

**usage in view(s)**

```
@(title: String)
@import myapi.MyMagic._

@main("Welcome to Play") {

    @title.upperWords() <br>
    @{"foo bar baz".upperWords()} <br>
    @{"I'm bolded LOL".bold()} <br>

    <ul>
        @for(item <- 1 to 10){
            <li >Item no.: @{item} @{"(first item)".when(item==1)}</li>
        }
    </ul>    
}
```

Comment: In second case I think the methods can return for example just a String. In that case I would not need to use Html() to avoid escaping.

Comment: By the way, the question was about having reusable functions in templates - it looks like it is impossible to have that. I think you should put that in the answer before mentioning how to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new file named `title.scala.html` with these contents:

```
@(text: String)

@title(text: String) = @{
    text.split(' ').map(_.capitalize).mkString(" ")
}

@title(text)
```

Then you can use it in your templates as you would like.

Comment: But the result is going to contain all those new lines which appear in title.scala.html. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: no I don't think so, not with this approach, but the whitespace shouldn't affect the appearance of your html page though.